# C++ - Parsing file iterating twice over last line

Tags: c++, file

I currently have a text file that looks like the following:

California 22 23

Washington 43 11

Oklahoma 98 23

The format of each line is string, double, double. Each is separated by a single space. I have the following method to read the file, however it seems to iterate over the last line of the text file twice, why is this? (i.e. it creates two City objects with the name 'Oklahoma')

```
void openFile() {

    string line, name;
    double latitude, longitude;

    ifstream thefile("text.txt");
    if (thefile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(thefile, line)) {
            std::stringstream n(line);
            n >> name >> latitude >> longitude;
            City newCity(name, latitude, longitude);
            addNode(newCity);
        }
        thefile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing it iterate twice over the last line while stepping through the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bet is that the last line of the file is a blank line, causing

```
n >> name >> latitude >> longitude;
```

to fail quietly (because you don't check whether input succeeded), and the variables line, name, latitude, and longitude keep their values from the previous successful entry.

How to fix this:

First, keep your variables' scope as narrow as possible: defined line, name, latitude, and longitude inside the loop.

Second, always check that your operation (such as >>) succeeded.

Comment: Yes you were correct, I had an extra blank line on the text file which appears to have been causing this, thank you!